# How can I get tooltips showing in dygraphs without annotation

Tags: javascript, r, dygraphs

I am trying to use the R implementation of dygraphs

The example provided is

```
library(dygraphs)

dygraph(presidents, main = "Presidential Approval") %>%
dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(0, 100)) %>%
dyAnnotation("1950-7-1", text = "A", tooltip = "Korea") %>%
dyAnnotation("1965-1-1", text = "B",  tooltip = "Vietnam")
```

which results in the chart[image]

Hovering over the 'A' produces a tooltip with 'Korea'

I am keen to have a tooltip for every point preferably dispensing entirely with the text requirement - though setting text to "" with minimal height/width values might suffice. I would also want to attach the dyAnnotations programmatically from a file with date and tooltip columns

```
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("1950-7-1","1965-1-1")),tooltip=c("Korea","Vietnam"))
```

Is this feasible,and, if so, how?
TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, as promised, here is a start to how we might use the legend for your information.  We crudely overwrite the legend.  This behavior can be made much more polite if you also want a legend.  In addition, you could provide an object/hash with a `data.frame` to lookup the `x` and return an informative description.

I added a `debugger` so if you open your debugger in Chrome, etc. you can see what is happening.

```
library(dygraphs)

dyG = dygraph(presidents, main = "Presidential Approval") %>%
    dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(0, 100))

#  explore the legend route
dyG %>%
    dyCallbacks(
        highlightCallback = sprintf(
'function(e, x, pts, row) {

// added to illustrate what is happening
//   remove once satisfied with your code
debugger;  

var customLegend = %s

// should get our htmlwidget
e.target.parentNode.parentNode
  .querySelectorAll(".dygraph-legend")[0]
  .innerText = customLegend[row] + row;
}'
            ,# supply a vector or text that you would like
            jsonlite::toJSON(rep('something here',length(as.vector(presidents))))
        )
    )
```

Below, I have changed to add to the legend rather than replace.

```
#  explore the legend route
#    add to legend rather than replace
dyG %>%
  dyCallbacks(
    highlightCallback = sprintf(
      'function(e, x, pts, row) {

      // added to illustrate what is happening
      //   remove once satisfied with your code
      debugger;  

      var customLegend = %s


      // should get our htmlwidget
      var legendel = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
        .querySelectorAll(".dygraph-legend")[0];

      // should get our htmlwidget
      legendel.innerHTML = legendel.innerHTML + "<br>" + customLegend[row];
      }'
            ,# supply a vector or text that you would like
      jsonlite::toJSON(rep('something here',length(as.vector(presidents))))
    )
  )
```

Comment: after thinking about this a bit, could have easily used `innerHTML` and add `<br>` to the legend instead of replacing so I added to my answer

Comment: This looks great. Especially with option to easily add extra line(s)

Answer (score 5):

Much of Dygraphs customization occurs in `CSS` styling.  For example, [here is how](https://gist.github.com/timelyportfolio/cf7b94048ffe7b6a0112) we can change the default tooltip behavior.  With this in mind and a little help from [Dygraphs annotation documentation](http://dygraphs.com/annotations.html), we can do something like this for the first question.

```
# answers Stack Overflow question
#   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671576/how-can-i-get-tooltips-showing-in-dygraphs-without-annotation
# on how to customize annotations

library(dygraphs)

# question is two parts - let's handle part 1 first
dygraph(presidents, main = "Presidential Approval") %>%
  dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(0, 100))  %>%
  dyAnnotation("1950-7-1", text = "Korea", tooltip = ""
               # this is not necessary but think it better to be specific
               ,cssClass = "specialAnnotation") %>%
  # will leave this as before 
  dyAnnotation("1965-1-1", text = "Vietnam", tooltip = "") -> dyG

#this is a hack to set css directly
#  dyCSS designed to read a text css file
dyG$x$css = "
  /* if cssClass not assigned use .dygraphDefaultAnnotation */
  /*  !important is critical for the rules to be applied */
  .specialAnnotation {
    overflow: visible !important;
    width: initial !important;
  }
"
```

for the second question, here is one way we can accomplish this

```
# now for part 2 
dyG = dygraph(presidents, main = "Presidential Approval") %>%
  dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(0, 100))

tooltips = list(
  list(x = "1950-7-1", tooltip = "", text = "Korea")
  ,list(x = "1965-1-1", tooltip = "", text = "Vietnam")
) 

annotator <- function(x,y){
  d = do.call(dyAnnotation,modifyList(list(dygraph=x),y))
  return(d)
}

dyG = Reduce( annotator, tooltips, init=dyG )

#this is a hack to set css directly
#  dyCSS designed to read a text css file
dyG$x$css = "
  /* if cssClass not assigned use .dygraphDefaultAnnotation */
  /*  !important is critical for the rules to be applied */
  .dygraphDefaultAnnotation {
    overflow: visible !important;
    width: initial !important;
    border: none !important;
    font-size: 200% !important;
  }
"

dyG
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Couple of points. a) Is there a way of doing this via the tooltip rather than text? It does not make much difference in this example but I had in mind for real life something like a basketball game where there would be lines for the scores and tooltips for each play by play. I wouldnt want them all showing at once cluttering up the plot b) How do I get from vectors for x=c("1950-7-1","1965-1-1") and text=c("Korea","Vietnam") to the list format for tooltips

Comment: so do you want the tooltip like a traditional tooltip and not the uncustomizable `title` method used by dygraphs?  what do you want to be the marker/indicator that a tooltip might occur?  I am wondering if the legend is a better option.

Comment: The legend would certainly be a good alternative, so  in the basketball for example it might show "PHO 33 MIN 35 6:43 Goran Dragic makes a tip shot." when hovering over a point on the line at 6mins 43sec of the game. Then there would be no reason to have a text or tooltip showing

Comment: Not quite the solution I was after but the info you provided was well worth the bounty Tx

Comment: never worked for a bounty before;  did you figure this out?  I can try to put a working example together if you would like.

Comment: I haven't got any further so yes please