# Dygraph annotations using data in a data frame

Tags: r, annotations, dygraphs, shiny

I have a timeseries plotted using a dygraph in a shiny app.  Now I want to place annotations onto the chart using a data frame which has a date column and an event name.  It works when I specify the row number of the dataframe in the annotation statement but I want all the points in the data frame annotated.  The rows in the data frame will change based on user input

Use Case Code:

```
colnames(ci)<-colnames(fspanel2aplot)       
    dygraph(ci) %>%
      dySeries(colnames(ci)[2], color = "green",strokeWidth = 2,pointSize = 5) %>%
      dySeries(colnames(ci)[3], color = "black",strokeWidth = 2,axis = 'y2') %>%
      dyLegend(width = 650) %>%
      dyAxis("y", label = "Fundamental Indicator") %>% 
      dyAxis("y2", label = "Technical Indicator") %>%
      dyRangeSelector() %>%
      dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, "Set2"),
                axisLineWidth = 1.5, fillGraph = FALSE,
                drawGrid = FALSE, axisLabelFontSize=12,
                connectSeparatedPoints = TRUE,labelsKMB=TRUE) %>%
      dyAnnotation(DTFRAME$EX_DT[1], text = "A", tooltip = DTFRAME$RATIO[1],series=colnames(ci)[3])
```

Can I use a loop to place all annotations in the DTFRAME onto the dygraph.

Thank you
SD

Comment: Can you provide sample of your data `dput(ci)` please

Comment: so there is date in the form of row names and two series fundamental and technical.

Comment: please provide sample data!

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I got the solution from a separate post

Comment: I will post the link here in sometime once I reach home

Comment: I will post the solution once in sometime

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671576/how-can-i-get-tooltips-showing-in-dygraphs-without-annotation - I got my answer from this post